# Other vertices affected when moving one vertex

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

I have a mesh that I have not created myself. I took an existing mesh and started modifying it for my own purposes. Suddenly I notice some vertices go crazy when I move (or grab) certain vertices.

This is NOT due to proportional editing as far as I can tell (hopefully you can tell as well from the gif).

I don't know how I got these vertices into that state, I have been removing edges, filling gaps with new faces etc on the mesh, and now this. Any idea how I can repair that state? From the image it appears to happen when vertex is moved, but it happens as soon as G is pressed if I do that instead.

[image: Moving some vertices make other go crazy]

Here's an image of some of the settings. You can see x-mirror and topology mirror is on. It seems it's the topology mirror that causes it, removing it stops the weird behaviour. And I don't need it and it doesn't make sense for this mesh, so my problem is solved for me. Maybe others have the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Are there any modifiers? specifically the Mirror modifier.

Comment: No. But I was going to add it later on. I did have x-symmetry on however which I checked because of your comment, and turning it off removes the problem. Not sure I understand why, but I can live without x-symmetry, so it does kinda solve it.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the settings and have you applied rotation/scaling and transform to the mesh CTRL+a ?

Comment: Which settings would you like a screenshot of?

Comment: the symmetry settings, can you confirm you did do CTRL+a on the mesh?